# Asus Xtion Not enough bandwidth

Tags: openni, xtion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use the Asus Xtion Pro camera with openni on Ubuntu 12.04. It does not work. Running *dmesg* in the terminal gives:

```
[15844.380294] usb 3-9: new high-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[15844.400319] usb 3-9: New USB device found, idVendor=1d27, idProduct=0600
[15844.400327] usb 3-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[15844.400333] usb 3-9: Product: PrimeSense Device
[15844.400337] usb 3-9: Manufacturer: PrimeSense
[15844.401720] usb 3-9: Not enough bandwidth for new device state.
[15844.401738] usb 3-9: can't set config #1, error -28
```

I've tried all the USB ports on the computer. It always gives the same error.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/106036/asus-xtion-not-enough-bandwidth/) by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 529 on 2013-11-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've solved this problem by deactivating **xHCI** and **EHCI Hand-off** in the bios of the motherboard.

---

Originally posted by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) with karma: 529 on 2013-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-12-04**:
Yup, that seems like a good solution. The Xtion and Kinect don't work on USB 3.0 (xhci) ports. If you're lucky, your PC has at least one USB 2.0 (ehci) port; otherwise, you have to disable xhci (either in the bios, or by blacklisting the kernel module).